# Is it possible to set title attribute and value to the HTML tag on the login page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-login, jquery-attributes

As of known Wordpress 5.2.0, `login_headertitle` has been deprecated and it is suggested to use `login_headertext` instead. However, I like to display a text when the login image is hovered on the login page. For this reason, I want to add the title attribute to the `#login h1` tag which is surrounding the login image on the login page. Then I want to add value to this title attribute. I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login h1').attr("title", "Our true mentor in life is science.");  
});
```

How do we add the title attribute to the `#login h1` tag and does it work?

**Edited after first comment:** When I look the Console, it gives an error like this: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined.` But on the below, we see that jQuery is defined as follows: `<script type='text/javascript' src='***/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></ script>`

However, even though the jQuery is attached to the page, the problem is solved when I make a definition like this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Why do I need to add jQuery again even though it is attached on the login page?

Comment: Your code should work. Do you get any js errors in the dev console?